# Akka 2.4 TCP w/ TLS

Tags: scala, akka, spray, akka-io

I'm trying to figure out how to use TLS (or SSL) with Akka IO. I realize that the pipeline stuff has been ripped out of Akka. They mentioned that they will have something shiny and new in the 2.4 release of Akka, but I don't see anything in the documentation and can't find any examples.

How does one go about enabling TLS for an Akka Tcp Server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 2.4 release yet. The replacement for the old pipelines is Akka Streams (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M5/scala.html) which is closing on on 1.0, and eventually becomes an experimental module of 2.4. TLS support is expected to come in Akka Streams 1.0-RC1 in a few weeks.

EDIT FROM THE FUTURE: It has been a few weeks and TLS support has been released in RC1. The documentation is still thin, but you can find some here http://doc.akka.io/api/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-RC2/#akka.stream.io.SslTls$